# D/OpenGLRenderer: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library for resizing images. I can't save the image. I am getting the following two errors on the debug console:

> E/OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.

> D/OpenGLRenderer: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';

  Future resizeImage() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      var image = img.decodeNamedImage(pickedImage.path, File(pickedImage.path).readAsBytesSync());
      if (image != null) {
        var thumbnail = img.copyResize(image, width: 120);
        Uint8List bytes = thumbnail.getBytes();
        await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(bytes,
             name: "new_image.jpg");
      }
    }
  }
```

pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image: ^4.1.3
  image_gallery_saver: ^2.0.3
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
```